# Issue with dynamic sql

Tags: postgresql

Hi every one I have multiple spatial tables That I want to control, so that I created a table where I will store the name of the operation applied on my layers tables(insert,update or delete), operation time and the team who did it, number of spatial tables created.

> My script table

```
   CREATE TABLE public.monitoring_table
(
    operation character(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    operat_ime timestamp without time zone,
    userid text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    dc_team text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    number_pts_created integer,
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('monitoring_table_id_seq'::regclass),
    CONSTRAINT monitoring_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.monitoring_table
    OWNER to postgres;
```

after that I stored all the teams that I have on my table :

```
insert into monitoring_table (dc_team) values ('abdoulhassan');
insert into monitoring_table (dc_team) values ('abdoulei');
insert into monitoring_table (dc_team) values ('danis');
insert into monitoring_table (dc_team) values ('david');
insert into monitoring_table (dc_team) values ('joseph');
```

To calculate the number of spatial tables created, I executed this function :

> My counting function :

```
DROP FUNCTION get_dc_team_counting();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dc_team_counting()
  RETURNS bigint AS  
$func$
DECLARE
    dc_team text;
    _tbl_pattern text;
    _schema text = 'sige';
   _tb_name information_schema.tables.table_name%TYPE;  
   _tc      bigint;  
BEGIN
   FOR _tb_name IN
      SELECT table_name
      FROM   information_schema.tables
      WHERE  table_schema = _schema
      AND    table_name   ~ _tbl_pattern  
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) FROM %I.%I where id= 583', _schema, _tb_name)
      INTO _tc; 
      return _tc;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

To get the team I executed this function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_team()
  RETURNS text AS  -- or whatever you want to return
$func$
DECLARE
    dc_team text;
    _tbl_pattern text;
    _schema text = 'public';
   _tb_name information_schema.tables.table_name%TYPE;  -- currently varchar
   _tc     text;  
BEGIN
   FOR _tb_name IN
      SELECT table_name
      FROM   information_schema.tables
      WHERE  table_schema = _schema
      AND    table_name   ~ _tbl_pattern  -- see below!
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format('SELECT dc_team FROM %I.%I where id = 26', _schema, _tb_name)
      INTO _tc; 
      return _tc;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In my where clause I want to get dynamically the value of the ID. I don't want to give it manually in the function. I don't see how to do it.

Now I created a trigger function to be able to update my table if a row was inserted, updated or deleted. I did it this way :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_monitoring() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $monitoring$


    BEGIN

        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            update monitoring_table set operation = 'D', operat_ime = now(), userid = user ,dc_team = OLD.dc_team, number_pts_created = get_dc_team_counting() where dc_team = get_team();
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            update  monitoring_table set operation = 'U',operat_ime =  now(),userid = user , dc_team = NEW.dc_team, number_pts_created = get_dc_team_counting() where dc_team = get_team();
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            update  monitoring_table set operation = 'I', operat_ime = now(), userid = user, dc_team = NEW.dc_team, number_pts_created = get_dc_team_counting() where dc_team = get_team();
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; 
    END;
$monitoring$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER monitoring
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON sige.valve
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_monitoring();
```

In my previous functions I used known values of ids in the where clauses, but when I try to insert or update a value on the concerned table I get this error :

```
the control attempted it's end without return
CONTEXT:  fonction PL/pgsql get_team()
instruction SQL « update  monitoring_table set operation = 'U',operat_ime =  now(),userid = user , dc_team = NEW.dc_team, number_pts_created = get_dc_team_counting() where dc_team = get_team() »
fonction PL/pgsql process_monitoring(), ligne 10 à instruction SQL
```

If you have any idea about the origin of the error and how to get dynamically a value of a field and put it in the where clause tell me please. 
I'm a newbie and I'm struggling, any assistance would be warmly appreciated.

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: The immediate problem seems to be that your queries filter on `table_name   ~ _tbl_pattern`  but  `_tbl_pattern` is not initialized.

Comment: `get_team()` will only get to `return` something if loop returns at least 1 row. If it does not, then function reaches its end without encountering any `return` keyword. You either need to return some default value or declare this function as returning set of text and stop loop after first iteration.